# Autolayout yellow warnings. Will it crash my app in run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout, uistoryboard

In storyboard , I am seeing a lot of yellow warning. Upon clicking the yellow warning , I get like update frame or update constraints. In the console it throws auto-layout warnings too. I just want to know whether it will crash my app because of this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyUcV.png)

Comment: The correct question here should not be will it crash but how can I fix them? What happens if you select update all frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yellow warnings and auto-layout warnings in console are **not** related.

Yellow warnings means that what you see in IB is not what you will get at runtime according to current constraints. If you want to see what you will get you should click yellow warning and press "update frame". If you want to get at runtime what you currently see in IB you should press yellow warning and select "update constraint".

Runtime warnings in console means some constraints conflict at runtime. You should analyse the warning message to find what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it will not. But I suggest you to fix them all.

Answer (score 0):

why not update all the frames, the difference Xcode complains about is not much, and NO it wont crash your application, BUT Xcode complains as there might be situations where your constraints wont work as per you set them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application will not crash weather it is a **Yellow** one or a **Red** one .

Xcode only means that the constrains you have kept may not work properly in different modes and resolutions .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix it by simply clicking on update constraints,but result may not be what you expected.
So click on yellow arrow and read suggestion by xcode.